# Can multiple thread simultaneously update records in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How can we update records in DynamoDB using multiple threads?
Let we have 100 of records and threads as t1, t2, t3, t4, t5
t1 attempts fist 20 records t2 next 20 and so on..
Is it possible ? if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AmazonDynamoDBAsync interface and with an ExecutorFactory providing at least 5 threads. Then, submit 100 UpdateItem requests asynchronously and wait for the results to come back by iterating over the Futures and calling get().